# Ubuntu 13.10 constantly grays out windows on good hardware

Tags: 13.10, usb-drive

I just built a new computer, (Intel i5 3570K 3.4GHz, 8GB RAM, 1GB NVidia GeForce GTX 650 Ti BOOST) and am running Ubuntu 13.10 on it on an 8GB flashdrive until I can get an actual hard drive.  When ever I am clicking GUI items, and 1/10 of the time the application will freeze, the whole window will fade to gray, and in 5-10 seconds will do what I clicked on and fade back to colored.  This makes the entire OS feel laggy and slow.  I didn't have this problem in Debian (I had other issues there).

I am having the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/232184/why-am-i-getting-grayed-out-windows-in-ubuntu-12-04.  Could my flashdrive be too slow?  What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Its a huge bug of compiz !
You can fix that by install the compiz config manager and disable the non responding windows shader. Its a must